# how to define a class without 'class' statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class

I have many classes to define, but I don't want to repeat the below work:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Is there any declaration statement to define a class without using the `class` statement?

Answer (score 7):

If you know in advance exactly which classes need to be defined, you should probably generate code that explicitly defines them with the `class` keyword for clarity.

However, if you really need to define them dynamically, you can use [`Object.const_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001690) in combination with [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Class.html#M002787). To define a couple of child classes of `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
%w{A B C D}.each do |name|
  Object.const_set name, Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
end
```

The result of the above is four new classes named `A..D`, all children of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably better done using macros or scripts in your text editor. Creating classes programatically makes them hard to document.

Comment: +1 for favoring code generation over runtime generation. The latter is sometimes the only way to do something, but it is usually not the best way.

Answer (score 3):

You can define classes completely dynamic:

```
A = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
  # this block is evaluated in the new class' context, so you can:
  # - call class methods like #has_many
  # - define methods using #define_method
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "Metaprogramming ruby" has a quiz question on how to avoid using the `class` keyword, but I'm not sure if that's going to help you fix your problem.